# Approximating a determinant by the matrix diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, approximation

I asked a related question on [Physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/368124/approximate-solutions-to-dysons-equation?noredirect=1#comment823995_368124), but it hasn't received much attention and I think it may be more of a mathematical problem than a physical one.

Suppose I wish to solve $$det(x\mathbb{I}-\mathbb{A})=0$$ for $x$ assuming the matrix $\mathbb{A}$ is not diagonal in general and $\mathbb{I}$ is the identity. What error do I incur by ignoring the off-diagonal elements of $\mathbb{A}$ to approximate the solution? Is there a general way to know, based on properties of the matrix, how good/poor this approximation is (for example, some sort of error bound)?

Comment: You cannot in general ignore the off-diagonal entries unless you they are smaller then the diagonal ones.  As an extreme example look at $M=\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\ -1&0\end{array}\right)$.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero That's true. I think I may have oversimplified my question now that I think about it. I'm going to edit it to make it a little closer to the question that motivated this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is related to the derivative of the determinant: [Wikipedia: Jacobi's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula)

This is how I interpret your post in Physic SE:

> To find the **lowest order correction** to these Koopman's theorem results, let us ignore the off-diagonal elements of Σ(E).

If your matrix $A=D+hB$ where $D$ is diagonal, and $h\ll 1$.

To simplify, let assume $A$ contains no zero diagonal element, so $D$ is invertible.

$$\det(A)=\det(D)+h\det(D)\operatorname{tr}(D^{-1}B)+o(h)$$

So when the diagonal is dominant and the rest of the matrix $hB$ is of lower order (i.e. negligible compared to the diagonal) then the determinant is approximable by $\det(D)$.

*When $D$ is not invertible, the formula is a little bit more complicated (see Wiki's page), but I think you get the principle.*

Answer (score 3):

If $\mathbb{A}$ is of the form $\Lambda+\epsilon \mathbb{B}$ where $\Lambda$ is diagonal and $\epsilon$ "small", then basically you use standard [perturbation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory_(quantum_mechanics)#Time-independent_perturbation_theory) with all the caveats therein. This will allow you to approximate the eigenvalues as a series in $\epsilon$.  The determinant is then the product of the eigenvalues.  After all, perturbation theory is just approximate diagonalization order by order.

Comment: I hadn't thought of this. It seems odd to me because the authors of the book from the other post obtain two different approximations to second order of the self energy, one which is strictly diagonal and the other isn't. I guess they could hypothetically be essentially doing two perturbation expansions.